# What does the change in *args and **kwargs in Python 3.5 mean?

Tags: python, syntax-error, python-3.5, args, keyword-argument

From the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.5.html#changes-in-python-behavior)

> Due to an oversight, earlier Python versions erroneously accepted the following syntax:

```
f(1 for x in [1], *args)
f(1 for x in [1], **kwargs)
```

> Python 3.5 now correctly raises a SyntaxError, as generator expressions must be put in parentheses if not a sole argument to a function.

---

What does that mean? Why is it that it's the wrong with the syntax above? Can someone show an example code of why is that a bad generator expression?

I think I understand it this much:

- there is a function `f()`
- that takes a generator, args and kwargs as its parameter

But why is the args and the kwargs usage wrong?

Comment: Background (just in case anyone asks): I'm debugging why the `nltk` code for `mwa_ppdb` works in Python < 3.5 but in Python 3.5 breaks when the kwargs somehow disappears when an object is imported with absolute import. I suspect it has to do with the changes from Python 3.4 -> 3.5. More details on https://github.com/nltk/nltk/pull/1627

Comment: The generator expression by itself is fine, the problem is that if it is not the *sole argument* to a function, then it must be in parentheses. This is part of the document grammer.

Comment: Thanks @juanpa.arrivillaga !!